# DNS Records Configuration - Going Straight to Spam Box?

Tags: dns, email, postfix, mail, dkim

I know that in order to hit the inbox, the main DNS records need to be properly set up. These are the main DNS records that every mail delivery system should have for their domain:

- TLS
- A
- MX
- DKIM
- SPF
- DMARC
- rPTR

The ones that I mainly need help with configuring right now are the following records:

MX, DKIM, & SPF.

I have iRedMail installed on my domain at:
aaronsnewsletters dot com

What exactly should I set for the MX records if I set my main mail server to mail.aaronsnewsletters dot com?

Am I supposed to set the MX records for the root/apex of the domain or do I set them to aim at the "mail.aaronsnewsletters dot com"?

Also, what about the DKIM & SPF?

Am I supposed to try pointing at the root/apex or the subdomain with the "mail."?

Any support is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I used https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx to study your domain DNS setup and everything looks as expected for the mail server, MX records, and SPF record.  You've already met the basic requirements below, and next steps for you are to setup DKIM signing on your email server (and publish the public key) and lastly (and optionally) publish a DMARC policy as described closer to the end below.

Minimal Incoming email requirements:

- a server running an SMTP agent to receive mail for your domain.  This is the "inbound SMTP server" with typical hostname "mail.example.com".
- a DNS MX record for your top-level domain pointing to the above inbound email server hostname.
- a DNS A record for the inbound email server hostname (maps hostname to IPv4)
- an email client that accesses your received email (over POP3 or IMAP) stored on the inbound SMTP server for you domain.

Minimum Outgoing mail requirements:

- an email client to compose email, configured with the name of an SMTP submission server and your credentials on that server.
- an SMTP submission server, also call an "outbound SMTP server", configured to accept outbound email for your domain from clients, to authenticate the clients (will likely have a TLS certificate for inbound connections from clients), and then to forward those outbound email's to the Internet.
- Assuming that you manage the outbound SMTP server (may or may not be same server as the inbound SMTP server and may or may not even be part of your domain), then you also need to setup:

  - a DNS A record for the outbound server's primary hostname (part of the basic server setup). The SMTP server's configuration must be setup to announce its primary hostname when making outgoing connections (maybe mail.example.com).  Note, a different secondary hostname might also be mapped to this server for submission, such as smtp.example.com, which needs another A or CNAME record and a matching TLS certificate.
  - a DNS PTR record mapping the IPv4 address of the outbound email server to the outbound server's primary hostname.  This must be requested from the ISP providing Internet connection to your server AFTER you setup the server hostname A record.
- create an DNS SPF record on your top-level domain that includes your outbound SMTP server's IPv4 address or fully qualified domain name (mail.example.com), using the IPv4 address directly is best. You should do this even if you don't manage the submission server (the people who manage the submission server should tell you the right info for your SPF record to identify their outbound SMTP server, example [setup for google apps users](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786)).  The SPF record helps Internet servers have more confidence when receiving your email, but still doesn't protect someone from spoofing your domain name in the FROM: header of an email if they send the email from server on a domain they control by having envelope sender address (the MAIL FROM or envelope from) be their domain instead of yours.

Next I recommend sign outbound emails using DKIM to build a better reputation for your domain's email. Even if you don't own the outgoing email server, DKIM signing can still be done on their server if they provide you the public key information to publish.  There are websites that can [check your DKIM signing by sending them a test email](https://dkimvalidator.com/) I've found helpful.

- create public/private keypair on the outbound server and decide on a key selector name
- publish the public key in a DNS DKIM record for your top-level domain and key selector name

A final optional step is to publish a DMARC policy for your domain, again the goal is to help increase the confidence in email received from your domain.  This is the most complicated part and many domains do not yet have this in place. It's a big topic, but basically your DMARC policy tells the rest of the Internet what to expect when receiving email from your domain and what you wish them to do if they receive an email that does not meet your published expectations.  My understanding is that the best case is you setup DKIM signing and a restrictive DMARC policy, then you send all your outbound email through your server that does the DKIM signing.  Once that is done, the SPF record is not really necessary anymore because DKIM provides more comprehensive protection with authentication of the critical header data, especially the FROM: header.  [Google has some very good documentation on setting up a DMARC policy.](https://support.google.com/a/topic/2759254)  Good Luck!